# переменная в значении LIMIT sql запроса

Tags: php, mysql

есть такой код

```
$result28 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id_sub=$sub ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 10 ",$db),
```

как вместо 10 поставить переменную, которую можно будет передать потом через POST?

Answer (score 1):

```
$result28 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id_sub=$sub ORDER BY rand() LIMIT  " . $_POST['variable'] ,$db),
```

Comment: Не работает, LIMIT не видит переменную и не выдает результат

Comment: Значит в $_POST нету такой переменной

Comment: Через echo она отображается, а вот в LIMIT не вносится

Comment: Ну покажите думп переменной $_POST и как вы используете лимит

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так -

```
$result28 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id_sub=$sub ORDER BY rand() LIMIT ".$_POST['limit'], $db)
```

Правда в таком виде это будет идеальное место для [sql - иньекции](http://php.net/manual/ru/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: Так напишите `intval($_POST['limit'])` и забудьте про инъекцию. Если, конечно, `$sub`  то же очищен